# Single Sign On with Rails Server and React client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, security, single-sign-on, doorkeeper

I have a Rails API and a client written in React that is embedded to website A. I want to use single sign-on so that users logging in to website A and going to my React app are automatically logged in to the API.
I am using Devise to manage users and Doorkeeper to handle OAuth2.

Here is the scenario wanted :

- User logs in to website A which is a provider
- User goes to React app (embedded in website A), some user info is passed by website A to React app
- If user is unknown to Rails API, check that provider is website A and store user via Devise
- Get access token for this user and user info from API and send back to React App

I cannot add routes to website A so it's not possible to install a usual OAuth2 flow.

My idea was to pass a signature identifying user from website A to the React app, and sending it to the API to authenticate user.
I tried using the [doorkeeper-grants_assertion](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-grants_assertion) gem but I cannot wrap my head around this problem.

Which grant flow should I use for the user in that case ? How to integrate this strategy to omniauth ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: have u figured this out?